# What is underling Architecture of RxJava 2 Observable.intervalRange?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I am developing a quiz app and want to use Observable.intervalRange to timer stuff but as I seen lot of users are cheating some games using some applications by slowing down or increase timer of app. SO I want to ask that can I rely on Observable.intervalRange if its not hack-able by this kind of applications. 
Example [cheat-engine](https://hackerbot.net/pc/cheat-engine) and [x8speeder](https://x8speeder.com/)

Comment: There is no way to make sure that the timer has been sped up, if you can't rely on any timer. So excluding RxJava for that reason is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have experience with cheating engines, so I can't comment on if RxJava will defeat it (my guess is it won't), but I can tell you that intervalRange works by performing incrementing a long value every x intervalUnit (which are passed in as the intervalRange is specified), and then emitting that to whatever consumes it.

You can check the [official documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/range.html) here.